# Pass array Id's to mysql query

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 119256
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 247436
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 266197
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 256299
        )
)
```

And I want to pass this array id's one by one to following function where I written the mysql query.

```
$search->getInformation($ID);
```

Please help how can I do this.

Comment: You have not written any question. Wanting something is fine, but what do you want to ask? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i gues you need somthing like this:

```
foreach ($array_variable as $key => $value){
    $search->getInformation($value['ID']);
}
```

Comment: you have previous giveb only $value. you missed 'ID' key :) and you have edited your answer just seen our answer :)

Comment: well, i edited the qeustion when you guys gave the answer, but that will always be an yes or no...

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array_variable as $key => $value){
    $search->getInformation($value['ID']);
}
```